# SharePoint List Formatting; Float Left, 31 Items, Displays 10

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, json-formatting

When using this sample: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/blob/master/view-samples/document-library-thumbnails/document-library-thumbnails.json

All items should display as formatted and have paging. However, when the list has 31 items, using the formatting from the sample, the number of items displayed will always be no more than 10, no paging available. All works as expected when the list has 30 or fewer items. If the list has 31 or more, only 10 items will be displayed. I can remove one item, refresh, and then all works as expected. Add one more item, refresh, and the view will only show 10. Setting the root element style > float:none, save, refresh, will show all items again. Switching back to style > float:left will trigger the 10 item limit.

Has anyone else encountered this? Here is my JSON for the custom list formatting:

```
 {
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "a",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "ms-borderColor-neutralLight",
      "href": "[$p002ToolsUrl]"
    },
    "style": {
      "float": "left"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-themeLighterAlt ms-bgColor-themePrimary--hover ms-fontColor-white--hover"
        },
        "style": {
          "display": "flex",
          "flex-wrap": "wrap",
          "flex-direction": "column",
          "align-items": "stretch",
          "padding": "1px",
          "margin": "10px",
          "max-width": "930px",
          "box-shadow": "2px 2px 4px darkgrey"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "img",
            "attributes": {
              "src": "[$p002ToolsImg]"
            },
            "style": {
              "width": "auto",
              "height": "300px"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "span",
                "txtContent": "[$Title]",
                "style": {
                  "margin-bottom": "1px"
                },
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontSize-m ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any item limit set in list view settings?

Comment: @GaneshSanap I tried various limits and settings in the list. None of them impacted the issue at the time of the post.